# google maps - pick value from array and assign to marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, variables, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I have been trying for the last 2 hours to find out what to do but cant seem to find the answer. What I am trying to do is I have 5 different markers numbered 1,2,3,4,5 at the end and also grouped into 2 categories (1 and 2). I also have an Info-window and when I click on specific marker number 3, I would like the info-window to open. In the infowindow code i have marker: ,. What can I add there to link to specific marker ?  Thank you very much folks

P.s. It only shows me the infowindow when I put marker: newevent;. The info window will be shown for the fifth marker for some reason.

```
 var beaches = [
 ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 1,1],
 ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 1,2],
 ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 2,3],
 ['Manly Beach', -33.800101, 151.287478, 2,4],
 ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 2,5]     ];



  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 10,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.88, 151.28),
  styles: mapStyle });


 newevent.category = beaches[i][3];
 markers.push(newevent);
```

}

```
 function displayMarkers(category) {
 var i;
 for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
   if (markers[i].category === category) {
     markers[i].setVisible(true);
   }
   else {
     markers[i].setVisible(false);
   }
 }
```

}

and the infowindow:

```
var info = new SnazzyInfoWindow({
    marker: ,
    placement: 'right',
    offset: {
        left: '20px'
    },
```

etc..

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give you an idea that I think you can use to solve your issue. What about when you create your markers give an unique ID to them..for instance if you have a function to create the markers:

```
var uniqueId = 1;
//more code    
function addMarker(location) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location,
      map: map
  });
  marker.id = uniqueId;
  uniqueId++;
}
```

So now you can link whatever you want to do with any specific marker, for example if you want to delete one specific marker and you have a function to delete markers:

```
  function deleteMarker(id) {

  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      if (markers[i].id == id) {

          markers[i].setMap(null);


          markers.splice(i, 1);
          return;
      }
  }
};
```

you can pass the Id as a parameter...or use an if, for instance:

```
if (uniqueId == 3 ) {
//Do whatever I want
}
```